# JavaScript Modify Object Prototype to Monitor Changes

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I'm trying to modify the `Object` prototype to allow for monitoring of changes on an entire object (not just a property like with `Object.watch`) using string comparison. Below is what I have so far, which is working as long as I call `myobj.change(...)` after each modification.

What I'm hoping to accomplish is a way to "re-bind" the `.change()` to the object each time it's modified so I can setup a single change handler that responds whenever the object is manipulated.

```
if (!Object.prototype.change) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "change", {
        value: function(handler) {
            var curVal = JSON.stringify(this);
            console.log('CUR:',curVal);
            console.log('STATE:', this.__proto__.state);
            if (curVal!==this.__proto__.state) {
                this.__proto__.state = JSON.stringify(this);
                handler.call(this);
            }
        }
    });
}

var myobj = { foo: 'bar' };
myobj.change(function(){
    console.log('Changed!');
});

myobj = { foo: 'qux' };
myobj.change(function(){
    console.log('Changed!');
});

myobj = { foo: 'sit' };
myobj.change(function(){
    console.log('Changed!');
});
```

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/fluidbyte/GE9t3/

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing because what is "monitoring changes on an entire object" if not monitoring the changes to the properties of the object? Are you looking to monitor changes to *all* properties?

Answer (score 2):

### WatchAll object

Here's some quick and dirty code to watch for changes to any property defined on the object. It requires that you initialize a new object of a certain type, `WatchAll`.

#### Code

```
var WatchAll = function (properties, change_handlers) {
  var obj = Object.create(null);
  var key;
  var i;
  for (key in properties) {
    obj[key] = null;
    Object.defineProperty(this, key, {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
      get: function () {
        return obj[key];
      },
      set: function (new_value) {
        var old_value = obj[key];
        obj[key] = new_value;
        // notify the change handlers
        for (i = 0; i < change_handlers.length; i++) {
          change_handlers[i](key, old_value, new_value);
        }
      }
    });
    this[key] = properties[key];
  }
};

function logUpdatedProperty (key, old_value, new_value) {
  console.log(key + ' was changed from ' + old_value + ' to ' + new_value);
}

var myobj = new WatchAll({ foo: 'bar', testing: 123 }, [logUpdatedProperty]);
myobj.foo = 'qux';   // from bar to qux
myobj.foo = 'sit';   // from qux to sit
myobj.testing = 456; // from 123 to 456
myobj.foo = 'bar';   // from sit to bar
myobj.testing = 123; // from 456 to test
```

#### JavaScript Version/Browser Compatibility

I tested the code with NodeJS but it should work in any browser (except IE8 and IE7 of course). [Here's the browser compatibility table for Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Browser_compatibility).

### Wrap existing objects with WatchAll

To wrap existing objects, you could just enumerate over their properties and copy their values to the new WatchAll object with the right change handler:

```
function wrapWithWatchAll (obj, change_handlers) {
  var propagateChangeBackToOriginalObject = function (key, old_value, new_value) {
    obj[key] = new_value;
  };
  return new WatchAll(obj, [propagateChangeBackToOriginalObject].concat(change_handlers));
}

var existingobj = { name: 'omouse', skills: 'programming' };
var wrappedobj = wrapWithWatchAll(existingobj, [logUpdatedProperty]);
wrappedobj.name = 'rudolf';                   // from omouse to rudolf
wrappedobj.skills = 'javascript';             // from programming to javascript
console.log('wrapped: ' + wrappedobj.name);   // rudolf
console.log('existing: ' + existingobj.name); // rudolf
```

The issue here is that you're going to have to use the wrapped object everywhere, so you'll have to swap the existing object with the wrapped object.